# I want to write a c programme that will reverse the first half of an integer

Tags: c, reverse

I want to write a program. The function should reverse the first half digits of n.
For example, if n = 3545, then ret should be 5345 or
if n = 65741, then ret should be 56741. But in my program, when I give 65741 as input and it gives me 75641 as output. So what should I add to get the required output.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>



int ReverseFirstHalf(int n)
{

int ret = 0, i = 0;

char arr[sizeof(n)];

do
{
    arr[i++] = n % 10;
}
while (n = n / 10);

for (int j = i / 2; j < i; j++)
{
    ret = ret * 10 + arr[j];
}
for (int j = i / 2; j--;)
{
    ret = ret * 10 + arr[j];
}
printf("After Reversing first half= %d\n", ret);
}



int main()
{
int n;
printf("Enter the value of n: ");
scanf("%d",&n);

ReverseFirstHalf(n);
}
```

Comment: `j = i / 2` rounds down when `i` is an odd number. To round up, it would be `j = (i+1) / 2`

Comment: btw: `sizeof(n)` is the size of an `int` which is typically 4 (or 2 or 8 on some systems). I would declare the array as `char arr[32]`.